# Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering, but have matching URL name

Tags: python, django, url, error-handling

As the title implies I've got the NoReverseMatch error, but my url.py has the corresponding named url.  I feel pretty confident I've missed something simple, but being new I can't seem to find my own problem.

---

**ERROR:** (Generated in the below employee_edit.html file)

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''employee_new''
>   with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

**\home\username\mysite\myapp\views.py:**

```
class v_EmployeeCreate(CreateView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employee/employee_edit.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('employee_list')
```

**\home\username\mysite\url.py:**

```
from myapp.views import v_EmployeeCreate, v_EmployeeList 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
< ... snip ...>
url(r'^newEmployee$', v_EmployeeCreate.as_view(), name="employee_new"),
)
```

**\home\username\mysite\myapp\templates\employee\employee_edit.html (line 7):**
`<form action="{% url 'employee_new' %}" method="POST">`

---

I feel like there is a file path issue, but I'm not sure how I would resolve that.  The named URL works to get me to the template, but then the template itself fails to generate a url.

For the sake of documentation so far I have:

1. reloaded django
2. checked spelling
3. confirmed non-template functionality (Same setup without the template tags is fine. page loads)

Working from tutorial: http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/views.html#creating-contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using an old version of Django - before 1.5 (current is 1.6). The clue is that your error message has *two* single-quotes around the view name: in those older versions, you shouldn't put quotes around the name in the `url` tag.

You should (preferably) upgrade Django, or (if you really can't do that) use `{% url employee_new %}`

Comment: /facedesk  That's it.  I'm using PythonAnywhere to learn so just assumed they would be using the lastest or maybe -1 version.  I didn't even think to look for docs older than 1.5.